# Group by and sumproduct in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to group by the values in one column based on another and then use the sumproduct (all in one formula, without additional column).

Here is my example table. Unfortunately I don't know how to create table, but here is the link to the image of table: https://ibb.co/9pLcQ89

```
Country M/F number of people  
US      M   50  
US      F   40  
UK      M   75  
UK      F   60
```

I want to get the following result. First to group by by country:

```
US = 90
UK = 135
```

The next step is to use `SUMPRODUCT`:  `90*90+135*135=26325`

And finally my result should be: `SQRT(26325)=162.2498`

My biggest concern is how to get the group numbers using one formula without using the names US and UK?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you multiplying `90*90` and `135*135`, because there are two "US", so you want the total "US" multiplied by the number of occurrences?

Comment: Well, I just gave some simple example. This is not my real table. But the problem is real. :)

Comment: Can you please give more detail in the example? I provided an answer but it may not work if your real data is different. I assumed you want to take the sum of each country, and raise it to a power (that power being the number of times that country appears in the first column), and goes from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array formula will create the unique list and do the math:

```
=SQRT(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW(A2:A5)=MATCH(A2:A5,A:A,0),ROW(A2:A5)*{1,1}))))),C:C)^COUNTIF(A:A,INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW(A2:A5)=MATCH(A2:A5,A:A,0),ROW(A2:A5)*{1,1}))))))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

By changing the references it does not matter the number of countries, the range will grow as needed:

```
=SQRT(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))=MATCH(A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),A:A,0),ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))*{1,1}))))),C:C)^COUNTIF(A:A,INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))=MATCH(A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),A:A,0),ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))*{1,1}))))))))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Woah - nice answer. Does the `N()` part help to automatically pick up the different countries? Say if OP also had "Canada", would this automatically adjust for that, whereas my answer requires OP to add to the "list" of `If/Countif()` bits to adjust for the various countries?

Comment: The range references would need to be updated but yes it does not matter the number of countries.

Comment: @BruceWayne now it is dynamic that as the list extends it will include any additions automatically.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen `N()` used before, so good to look in to that.  Brilliant answer, thanks :D

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution, but it does not work for me. I really don't know why. I just copied your formula....

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode? @Kyoto

Comment: When I use Ctrl-Shift-Enter it gives me error. But When I use just Enter it returns 90. :/

Comment: Not sure why, it is working for me as you can see in the pictures above.

Comment: I get the error because it wants to calcute: `=SQRT(SUMPRODUCT({0}^{0}))` wich returns error. I guess my Excel does not work with such fancy formulas. :)

Comment: Then your data is not as you show it or you are using full column references that include empty cells.

Comment: This  part of function does not do as in your excel: `MODE.MULT(IF({TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE};{2;3;4;5}*{1;1}))` because the result of `{2;3;4;5}*{1;1}` is `{2;3;#N/A;#N/A}`. Have any clue on what it could be. I have the exact same table/data as you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula (entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>):

```
=SQRT((SUMPRODUCT(IF(A2:A5="US",C2:C5))^COUNTIF(A2:A5,"US"))+(SUMPRODUCT(IF(A2:A5="UK",C2:C5)) ^COUNTIF(A2:A5,"UK")))
```

[image]