# excell SUMPRODUCT multiple criteria across multiple sheets

Tags: excel

Trying to do multiple criteria across multiple sheets

- L is the list of the sheets names to pull form
- K is the the ID number to count
- A is the the ID you would like counted

  `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""&L2:L13&"!k2:k146"),A3))`

Trying to figure out who to add a date criteria
so the output would show:

- ID X was entered 10 times on Date
- S is my date column

need to add to the !S2:S146"),B2))
B2 is the date to search for

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njWbh.png)

Comment: hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690837/group-by-and-sumproduct-in-excel